# Washy legend ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use the new guides system in ggplot2:

```
require(devtools)    
dev_mode()   
install_github("ggplot2")
require(ggplot2)

require(reshape2)
p <- ggplot(melt(outer(1:4, 1:4)), aes(x=Var1, y=Var2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=value))
p + guides(fill = guide_colorbar())
```

However the legend looks some kind of washy (not like all the other examples I have seen):
[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reshape2_1.2.1  ggplot2_0.9.0   devtools_0.6    gridSVG_0.8-1   proto_0.3-9.2   rgeos_0.2-3     stringr_0.6     gpclib_1.5-1   
 [9] maptools_0.8-14 lattice_0.20-0  sp_0.9-95       foreign_0.8-49 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.1       MASS_7.3-17        memoise_0.1        munsell_0.3       
 [7] plyr_1.7.1         RColorBrewer_1.0-5 RCurl_1.91-1       scales_0.2.0       tools_2.14.1
```

Comment: +1 for a very clear description of the problem.

Comment: Not sure but I would think this may happen under the combination of raster and some graphic devices. What happens with `guide_colorbar(raster = FALSE)`?

Comment: using raster = FALSE remove this washing, but then the legend has more grey horiontal lines (between the ticks) and does not look so pretty.

Comment: When I export it to pdf it all looks fine, so this is just in the display window.

Comment: Thanks. So this problem is of drawing raster on some device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks fine with the stable CRAN version of `ggplot2_0.9.0` and `reshape2_1.2.1`
Maybe you could report the bug [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues).

[image: Generated by ggplot 0.9.0]

Comment: Thanks for your post. I just run the code from shell and all looks fine. So this seems to be a RStudio bug - sorry haven´t mentioned that, because didnot think about that.

Comment: Great that you got this resolved. You should then report the bug to rstudio: http://support.rstudio.org/

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that this happens in RStudio 0.95.261 but not from shell.

Comment: I have reported [this](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/1773-problem-using-ggplot2_090-and-rstudio).

Comment: @EDi - howsabout you tick the little tick mark on this answer to get it accepted as the answer?

Comment: presumably the report should be for `Rstudio` and `rasterGrob`; I doubt ggplot2 is involved at all.

Comment: Only observed on Linux. Will be fixed in the next daily build of RStudio (rstudio-0.96.40-amd64). Thank you all and the guys from RStudio!